# How to add a button to a form in Dynamics CRM 2015

Tags: javascript, c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

for example, I want to add new control, such as a button:

`<a class="btn">Click Me</a>`

in the middle of (not ribbon) `Contact Form`. That by clicking on it, some code from C#(server) or JavaScript(client) execute.

[image]

Can anyone help me? (I'm new in CRM ,but not in C# and JS)

Comment: you need to create an HTML web resource

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Guido's comment (which is the correct solution) - after you create an HTML web resource with the button, and that button triggers whatever logic you want, add that web resource to the form directly, or else you can add an IFrame that points to the web resource.

Comment: How can I use `.aspx` file and programming with SDK? Would you please give me a sample code or refer to a good tutorial website?

Comment: Modifying the .aspx file is not supported and I would strongly recommend against that, especially when there is a supported way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: No, I don't modify .aspx files. I want to create a custom.aspx file and insert to the CRM as external resource. How can I do this, or something similar?

Comment: Get the CRM SDK from MSDN and look at the documentation included with that, it has a lot of examples on creating web resources.  You can also search MSDN directly for web resource examples.  The point is you don't create aspx files (server-side), but rather basic HTML files with embedded or referenced javascript.  You can also trigger server-side events such as plugins and workflows by taking some action in a web resource, that is also covered in the SDK documentation.